# How to fail Azure devops pipeline task specifically for failures in bash script

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am using Azure Devops pipeline and in that there is one task that will create KVM guest VM and once VM is created through packer inside the host it will run a bash script to check the status of services running inside the guest VM.
If any services are not running or thrown error then this bash script will exit with code 3 as i have added the value in bash script as below

set -e

So i want the task to fail if the above bash script fails, but issue is in the same task as KVM guest VM is getting created so while booting up and shutdown it throws expected errors but i dont want this task to fail due these error but to fail it only bash scripts fails.

i have selected the option in task "Fail on Standard Error"
But not sure how we can fail the task specifically for bash script error, can anyone have some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try and use `exit 1` command to have the bash task failed. And it is often a command you'll issue soon after an error is logged.

Additionally, you also may use [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#example-log-an-error) to customized a error message. Kindly refer to the sample below.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
exit 1
```

[image]